# Анимация окружности в 3djs

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Есть некая окружность. Появление которой нужно анимировать. Что то по типу окружности которая начинается в одной точке и через некоторое время смыкается.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var height = 138,
        width = 138,
        margin = 14,
        data = [{
            proposal: "proposal1", //невидимая область
            rate: 45,

          },
          {
            proposal: "proposal2", //видимая область
            rate: 135
          }
        ];

      // функция для получения цветов
      var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", "#4fb5ad"]);

      // задаем радиус
      var radius = Math.min(width - 2 * margin, height - 2 * margin) / 2; //задаем радиус которой впишеться в область

      // создаем элемент арки с радиусом
      var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius)
        .innerRadius(radius - 10)
        .endAngle(1);


      var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) {
          return d.rate;
        });
      //создание тега svg
      var svg = d3.select(".pie-graphic").append("svg")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height / 2) + ")");


      //Подложка серый круг
      svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 0)
        .attr("cy", 0)
        .attr("fill", "#f2f3f5")
        .attr("r", 0)
        .transition()
        .duration(760)
        .attr("r", 69);

      //Добавление всех частей диаграммы
      var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(data))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");


      g.append("path")
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return color(d.data.proposal);
        })
        .attr("d", arc);

      var circleAnin = g.selectAll('path');

      //Вот тут анимация почему то применяется сразу, а не через 760 мс
      d3.transition().duration(760).tween("name", function(t) {
        circleAnin.attr("d", arc.endAngle(0.1))
      });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pie-graphic"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге получился такой код для анимации смыкания круга.
Выбираем у элемента path. Задаем transition и время через duration. Потом у path выбираем атрибут d. И для него задаем кастомную анимацию через attrTween, во второй параметр передавая функцию, которая в принципе и будет анимировать.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var height = 138,
                width = 138,
                margin = 14,
                data = [{
                        proposal: "proposal1", //невидимая область
                        rate: 45,

                    },
                    {
                        proposal: "proposal2", //видимая область
                        rate: 135
                    }
                ];

            // функция для получения цветов
            var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .range(["rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)", "#4fb5ad"]);

            // задаем радиус
            var radius = Math.min(width - 2 * margin, height - 2 * margin) / 2; 

            // создаем элемент арки с радиусом
            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .outerRadius(radius)
                .innerRadius(radius - 10);



            var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                .sort(null)
                .value(function(d) {
                    return d.rate;
                });
            //создание тега svg
            var svg = d3.select(".pie-graphic").append("svg")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform",
                    "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height / 2) + ")");


            //Подложка серый круг
            svg.append("circle")
                .attr("cx", 0)
                .attr("cy", 0)
                .attr("fill", "#f2f3f5")
                .attr("r", 0)
                .transition()
                .duration(760)
                .attr("r", 69);

            //Добавление всех частей диаграммы
            var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
                .data(pie(data))
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "arc");


            g.append("path")
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return color(d.data.proposal);
                })
                .attr("d", arc);

            var circleAnin = g.selectAll('path');


            //Вот тут начинается анимация смыкания круга
            circleAnin
                .transition() 
                .duration(1000)
                .attrTween("d", tweenPie)
                .transition()


            function tweenPie(b) {
                b.innerRadius = 0;
                var i = d3.interpolate({
                    startAngle: 0,
                    endAngle: 0
                }, b);
                return function(t) {
                    return arc(i(t));
                };
            }

        });
```